# parent relative positioned and floated left child absolute positioned

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to have a set of parents with float left applied to them, but also with relative position, and inside each of them I have a div with position absolute like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="pa">
        <div id="apDiv1"><img src="images_1/logo-u16785.png" width="194" height="190"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pa">
        <div id="apDiv4"><img src="images_1/zilogo-u16782.png" width="194" height="190"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.wrapper {
  width:1300px;
  position: relative;
}

.pa {
  float:left;
  width:650px;
  position: relative;
}

#apDiv1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 650px;
  height: 190px;
  z-index: 4;
  left: 39px;
  top: 10px;
}

#apDiv4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 650px;
  height: 190px;
  z-index: 4;
  left: 39px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

now my problem, if u see, the 2 selectors has the same top and left, but because they are in 2 different, parent which are floated left and with position relative I thought the selectors should be positioned relative to their parent, but they are on top of each other, why??

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but first make sure your CSS classes and DIVs have the same name.

I changed `float: left;` from the **".pa"** div to `display: inline-block;`.

[Check my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKryJ/)

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly because the absolute-positioned elements aren't aware of the floated elements' boundaries, but I suspect most likely because you have styles for #apDiv1 and #apDiv2 but your actual element IDs are "apDiv1" and "apDiv4".

Comment: sorry was a mistake in the number, I changed, but I'm still have the same issue